# How to make n-D array into a string in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, string, random

I have a multi-dimensional array:

```
[
  [:C],
  [:C, [:C]],  
  [:C, [[:C]]],
  [:C, [:C, [:C]]],
  [:C, [:C, [:C, :C]]],  
  [:C, [:C, [:C, [:C]]]],
  [:C, [:C, [:C, [:C, :C]]]],
]
```

I need to translate it into a string like this:

```
"C C(C) C((C)) C(C(C)) C(C(CC)) C(C(CC)) C(C(C(C)))"
```

For clarity, here are the inner arrays, each shown with its translated string:

```
[:C]                       => "C"
[:C, [:C]]                 => "C(C)"
[:C, [[:C]]]               => "C((C))"
[:C, [:C, [:C]]]           => "C(C(C))"
[:C, [:C, [:C, :C]]]       => "C(C(CC))"
[:C, [:C, [:C, [:C]]]]     => "C(C(CC))"
[:C, [:C, [:C, [:C, :C]]]] => "C(C(C(C)))"
```

I've tried using the flatten and concatenate but I'm not getting the
desired result.  I want it with parentheses so that it can be easily
identified.  If I use `flatten` or `concat`, I get `CCCCCCCCCCCCC`. I
want it with parentheses.

Comment: Can you explain the logic of your requirements some more please?  It's not obvious why some Cs should have brackets in the output.  Some simpler examples would help.

Comment: `chemical=Array.new(l,[:C])`  The chemical is an N-d array. It has some branches attached to it. You see at the second C there is an array within array. So I want to distinguish it using the brackets.  @MaxWilliams

Comment: There's three levels of nesting there, so saying "there is an array within array" doesn't help very much.  Can you add some simple examples to your question of input which does not produce bracketed output and then a altered version of it which does?  Assume that nobody knows anything about your chemistry homework or whatever it is.

Comment: If there would'd be no arrays withing arrays then I can simply flatten or concat. Like for example: 
`[[:C, [":Br"]], [:C, [":Br"]], [:C, [":Br"]]]`  and the output should be CBrCBrCBr. But the main problem is arrays withing arrays. @MaxWilliams

Comment: Well, the whole thing is an array, with three arrays in it, and then they all have another array inside.  So, you've got three levels of nested arrays here.  So there are lots of arrays within arrays, but you're saying they shouldn't have brackets.  Please very clearly specify the rules of your requirements in your question, as just saying "arrays within arrays" isn't helping.

Comment: I don't understand how to elaborate it more. At each level of array i want to replace it with a bracket. If that'd help. This thing has been unsolved for so long, and I'm new in ruby. Would be glad if you could help me.  @MaxWilliams

Comment: I'm trying but you have not stated your requirements clearly.  Add these to your question, with the expected output for each, please, with each one on a seperate line:  `[:C]`, `[:C, [:C]]`, `[:C, [[:C]]]`, `[:C, [:C, [:C]]]`, `[:C, [:C, [:C, :C]]]`, `[:C, [:C, [:C, [:C]]]]`, `[:C, [:C, [:C, [:C, :C]]]]`

Comment: Okay. The output should be like the following, `C, C(C), C((C)), C(C(C)), C(C(CC)), C(C(CC)), C(C(C(C)))` Hope this helps. Thanks. @MaxWilliams

Comment: In your question please, each on a seperate line.

Comment: BTW this seems totally different to what you asked for in your original question.

Comment: I've modified the question. See if that fits. Any solutions so far ? @MaxWilliams

Comment: I'm getting `C C(C) C((C)) C(C(C)) C(C(CC)) C(C(C(C))) C(C(C(CC)))`. Verify.

Comment: Yeah that'd be the desired output. @D-side

Comment: That's not the output you have added to your question.  Please check them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm is straightforward once you notice that the first level and the others are formatted with different rules. So for clarity I had to use two different functions. Other than that, the algorithm is pretty self-explanatory. But even so I've commented it to be as clear as possible.

```
data = [:C], [:C, [:C]], [:C, [[:C]]], [:C, [:C, [:C]]],
       [:C, [:C, [:C, :C]]], [:C, [:C, [:C, [:C]]]],
       [:C, [:C, [:C, [:C, :C]]]]

def format_step(e) # Expects an array, since all the elements of data are arrays.
  e.map do |x| # So for each element, get the following
    if x.is_a?(Array)
      "(#{ format_step(x) })" # ...then call the same function on it
    else
      x.to_s # convert to string and return
    end
  end.join # this way map returns an array of strings here, join them
end

def reformat(data) # This rule is only for the first level and is a bit different
  data.map do |element| # For each element of the root array
    format_step(element) # do this
  end.join(' ') # ..and join the results with spaces
end

puts reformat(data)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot the second function did work. I didn't know much about mapping. Still learning. :D

Comment: @PriyaGupta well, they work together. Two rules, two functions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the requirements are this:

```
[:C]                       => "C"
[:C, [:C]]                 => "C(C)"
[:C, [[:C]]]               => "C(C)"
[:C, [:C, [:C]]]           => "C(C(C))"
[:C, [:C, [:C, :C]]]       => "C(C(CC))"
[:C, [:C, [:C, [:C]]]]     => "C(C(C(C)))"
[:C, [:C, [:C, [:C, :C]]]] => "C(C(C(CC)))"
```

Which isn't quite what your question says but is in D-Side's comment, I think this is what you want:  basically, replace all brackets apart from the outer ones with curly braces and remove the outer braces and unwanted formatting.

```
def to_formatted_string(array)
  array.inspect.gsub(/^\[|\]$|[\:\,\s]/,"").gsub("[","(").gsub("]",")")
end
```

tests = [
    [:C], 
    [:C, [:C]], 
    [:C, [[:C]]], 
    [:C, [:C, [:C]]], 
    [:C, [:C, [:C, :C]]], 
    [:C, [:C, [:C, [:C]]]],
    [:C, [:C, [:C, [:C, :C]]]]
]

```
tests.each{|arr| puts "#{arr.inspect} => #{to_formatted_string(arr).inspect}"};false
```

gives

```
[:C] => "C"
[:C, [:C]] => "C(C)"
[:C, [[:C]]] => "C((C))"
[:C, [:C, [:C]]] => "C(C(C))"
[:C, [:C, [:C, :C]]] => "C(C(CC))"
[:C, [:C, [:C, [:C]]]] => "C(C(C(C)))"
[:C, [:C, [:C, [:C, :C]]]] => "C(C(C(CC)))"
```

Comment: You are treating these as strings. This isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You can create string as you required as followed :

```
array = [:C], [:C, [:C]], [:C, [[:C]]], [:C, [:C, [:C]]], [:C, [:C, [:C, :C]]], [:C, [:C, [:C, [:C]]]], [:C, [:C, [:C, [:C, :C]]]]
array.inspect.gsub(/(\[|\]|:C)/, '[' => '(', ']' => ')',':C' => 'c')
```

Console Output:

```
2.1.2-p95 :029 > array = [:C], [:C, [:C]], [:C, [[:C]]], [:C, [:C, [:C]]], [:C, [:C, [:C, :C]]], [:C, [:C, [:C, [:C]]]], [:C, [:C, [:C, [:C, :C]]]]
 => [[:C], [:C, [:C]], [:C, [[:C]]], [:C, [:C, [:C]]], [:C, [:C, [:C, :C]]], [:C, [:C, [:C, [:C]]]], [:C, [:C, [:C, [:C, :C]]]]] 
2.1.2-p95 :030 > array.inspect.gsub(/(\[|\]|:C)/, '[' => '(', ']' => ')',':C' => 'c')
 => "((c), (c, (c)), (c, ((c))), (c, (c, (c))), (c, (c, (c, c))), (c, (c, (c, (c)))), (c, (c, (c, (c, c)))))"
```